# Using thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2 for json-rpc and getting following exception?

Tags: java, json, response, json-rpc

com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2SessionException: Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 response
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2Session.send(JSONRPC2Session.java:586)
    at JSON_RPC.Example_2.main(Example_2.java:82)
Caused by: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2ParseException: Invalid JSON
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Parser.parseJSONObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Parser.parseJSONRPC2Response(Unknown Source)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Response.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2Session.send(JSONRPC2Session.java:579)
    ... 1 more

My request object is:
{"id":"102","method":"listPath","params":{"token":"8b66666-4f66c-42cf-be45-70f666666c1","path":"/"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
And I am getting :
Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 response